# How to block the main thread until all the other threads finish executing?

Tags: python

This is a newbie question. I start 10 threads from my main thread. How do I stop the main thread from continuing until all the other threads finish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Join](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) all threads:

```
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Here `threads` is the list of your threads.